# VBA Dynamic Array without empty space

Tags: arrays, vba

I have two arrays: in the first one are names and in the second one there are country codes like this example:

```
array1(0)="Peter"     array2(0)="EN"
array1(1)="John"      array2(1)="US" 
array1(2)="Sandra"    array2(2)="FR"
array1(3)="Margot"    array2(3)="DE"
```

Now, I want to check the from an entry in a textbox1 if its a "FR" available in my arrays,if yes then save the positions in a third new array.

My code looks like this, but it is very bad and it does not work the way I want.

```vb
Dim name(0 To 9) As String

array1(0) = "Peter"
array1(1) = "John"
array1(2) = "Sandra"
array1(3) = "Margot"

Dim county(0 To 9)

county(0) = "EN"
county(1) = "US"
county(2) = "FR"
county(3) = "DE"

'Dim ArrayCounter
ArrayCounter = 0

Dim VarArray(9999)

For i = 0 To 9
    If county(i) = "DE" Then
        'ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
        'MsgBox (array1(i))

        VarArray(ArrayCounter) = i
        ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1

    End If
Next i

MsgBox (UBound(VarArray))
```

Now, if I check the third array, the array has to look like this:

```
array3(0)=2 'position of FR in my second array
```

Comment: "it dont work like i want" is not very helpful. What exactly is the problem? You say that you want `array3(0)=2` but in your code you use `varArray` and search for `"de"` so it should be `varArray(0)=3`?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct, i changed it in the describtion. i get an array whit empty sectors and i only want the not empty sectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty sectors"? As your code is now, `varArray` should stay empty because `"de"` is not the same as `"DE"`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct i changed again the description, sorry. if i run this code and make a msgbox i will get:
varArray(0)= ""; varArray(1)= "";varArray(2)= "2"

Comment: If I run the code as it is right now (changing `Dim name` to `Dim array1`) It works and I get `varArray(0) = 3`

Comment: My guess is that you set `VarArray(i) = i` instead `VarArray(ArrayCounter) = i`. Try to run the code before you post it so you don't have that many typos and inconsistencies between your post and your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the empty values in your `0 To 9999` array by redimming it:

```
If ArrayCounter > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve varArray(0 to ArrayCounter - 1) 'Preserve is important because otherwise it will delete the values
Else
    'do what you want to do if no match was found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you may be after the following:

```
Sub main()

    Dim names(0 To 9) As String
    names(0) = "Peter"
    names(1) = "John"
    names(2) = "Sandra"
    names(3) = "Margot"

    Dim county(0 To 9) As String
    county(0) = "EN"
    county(1) = "US"
    county(2) = "FR"
    county(3) = "DE"

    Dim ArrayCounter As Long
    ArrayCounter = 0

    Dim foundArray As Variant
    foundArray = county '<--| "copy" the 'county' array into 'foundArray', since this latter won't be bigger than the former

    Dim iFound As Long, iCounty As Long
    iFound = -1
    For iCounty = LBound(county) To UBound(county)
        If county(iCounty) = "DE" Then
            iFound = iFound + 1 '<-- update the 'foundArray' current counter
            foundArray(iFound) = iCounty '<-- update the 'foundArray' current counter content
        End If
    Next iCounty
    If iFound >= 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve foundArray(0 To iFound) '<--| if any values have been found, resize 'foundArray' up to the found items counter
    Else
        Erase foundArray '<--| otherwise erase it
    End If
End Sub
```